# Can we use javascript executor commands for Android mobile testing using appium.

Tags: javascript, android, appium

I am trying to use java script scroll command to scroll the page while automating android mobile native application to scroll the window dowm .But I am Getting error message :
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Not yet implemented. Please help us: http://appium.io/get-involved.html

Can you please tell me how to scroll down in Android mobile native application using Appium and Selenium Webdriver command.

Comment: Could you put here Java script command?

Answer (score 0):

**This message indicates that using javascript commands are not yet available for Android**

*All I can suggest is update appium when available, I'm sure they will implement it at some point.*

```
"org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Not yet implemented."
```

**Here's a method I use to touch swipe**

**ONLY TESTED ON IOS**

```
public static void touchSwipe(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY) throws WebDriverException{
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) TestSetup.AppElements.driver;
    js.executeScript("target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().scrollViews()[0].dragInsideWithOptions({startOffset:{x:0." + startX + ", y:0." + startY + "}, endOffset:{x:0." + endX + ", y:0." + endY + "}});");
}
```

**Example** *The swipe ints that you enter, should depend on where your view is.*

```
@Test
public void myTest() throws Exception {
    touchSwipe(75, 50, 75, 1); //Swipe downwards
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response  .As of now if there any way to scroll down the screen for IOS and Android while doing automation testing using APPium +web driver.

Comment: @PriyankaAgarwal Checkout my swipe example above

Comment: @NeilJaff,when i used your code i am getting message Not yet implemented.

Comment: @PramodKumarG what version of appium are you using? And are you developing for iOS or android?

Comment: @NeilJaff,I am using version AppiumForWindows-1.2.4.1 and i am developing for Android

Comment: @PramodKumarG I apologise, I've only tested this on iOS, I'll update my answer...